# Angular Scope issues with dynamic tab updates

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show angular Post data whenever a tab is clicked using ng-click event.
But it's not working.

What am i doing wrong here?.
First part of code works fine for switching Tabs, But i also want to show dynamic response when any tab is clicked & use it's tabNum as ?id=tabNum in ajax POST

```
angular.module('tabApp', [])
  .controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
      $scope.tab = newTab;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
      return $scope.tab === tabNum;

    };

}]);
```

I HAVE PROBLEM WITH FOLLOWING CODE, WHERE SHOULD I PLACE IT ?

> ```
> $http.get('http://localhost:8080/welcome.html?id=$tabNum')
>     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>       $scope.tab = data;
>     })
>     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>       // log error
> }); }]);
> ```

this is my HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MY
```

---

Reports

```
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="tabApp">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="TabController">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(1) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(1)">SHOW Manual Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(2) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(2)">SHOW ONE Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(3) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(3)">SHOW TWO Read Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(4) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(4)">SHOW THREE Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(5) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(5)">SHOW FOUR Read Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(6) }">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(6)">SHOW FIVE Read Admins</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <div ng-show="isSet(1)">
          <h1>CONTENT1</h1>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="isSet(2)">
          <h1>CONTENT2</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isSet(3)">
          <h1>CONTENT3</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isSet(4)">
          <h1>CONTENT4</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isSet(5)">
          <h1>CONTENT5</h1>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="isSet(6)">
          <h1>CONTENT6</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just create a service where you make the http call and call it from your controller. if you need more detail tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey as mentioned in my comment you can use a service for your http calls

```
.service('HttpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', 'Ls', 'CommonService', 'DateService', function ($rootScope, $http, Ls, CommonService, DateService) {
        return {
            CallService: function (url, callback) {                   
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data, status) {                            
                        callback(data, status);
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        callback(data, status);
                    });                 
            } 
        }
    });
```

Which can be called from the controller (dont forget to inject `HttpService`)

```
    .controller('TabController', ['$scope', 'HttpService', function($scope, HttpService) {
        $scope.tab = 1;

        $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
              $scope.tab = newTab;

            HttpService.CallService('http://localhost:8080/welcome.html?id='+newTab, function (data) {
                               $scope.tabdata = data;

            });
        };


        $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
          return $scope.tab === tabNum;

        };
```

the whole would look like this

```
angular.module('tabApp', [])
  .controller('TabController', ['$scope', 'HttpService', function($scope, HttpService) {
        $scope.tab = 1;

        $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
              $scope.tab = newTab;

            HttpService.CallService('http://localhost:8080/welcome.html?id='+newTab, function (data) {
                               $scope.tabdata = data;

            });
        };


        $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
          return $scope.tab === tabNum;

        };
}])

.service('HttpService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return {
            CallService: function (url, callback) {                   
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data, status) {                            
                        callback(data, status);
                    }).error(function (data, status) {
                        callback(data, status);
                    });                 
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @stackg91, Could you please show me how can i combine with my first part of code above?.

Comment: normally you would put services in a different file but for the example just right under the controller

Comment: I tried the whole block you provided, It says error -> ReferenceError: HttpService is not defined

Comment: you need to change the controller line i added 'HttpService' in the 2nd line 2x times, maybe you also need to switch service and controller so the service is defined before the controller just copy the service above the controller

Comment: May i know what should i change there in the CalService ?

Comment: You shouldnt have to change anything it should work like that you getting any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156482/discussion-between-serverliving-com-and-stackg91).

Comment: ReferenceError: HttpService is not defined –

Comment: Switch controller with service so service is first

Comment: Thats weird maybe change the name but have no ideas left sry this should definatly work

Comment: Thanks. Tried changing name of function, did not help , I will try to get this work.

Comment: Thanks. This one Worked. I did not see your latest changes in "Whole block"

Comment: I see that it's not filling the response data, do you see any reason for it ?.

Answer (score 1):

Mh maybe the get call maybe console log status and response

Comment: Console log shows the correct Data - any issue with  $scope.tabdata = data; ?

Comment: Ok. Now i got the data. thanks. Added {{tabdata}} to HTML divs